# displaying a json object in react native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I am creating an app that displays information which has been fetched from a json api.

I am able to fetch the json and print it to the console using console.log.

I would like to be able to print part of the json to the app such as location.

Here is the code I have tried

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
constructor (props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    loading: true,
    dataSource: []
  };
}
componentDidMount() {
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
 fetch('https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json', {
   method: 'GET',
   headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
 }).then((response) => response.json())
   .then((responseJson) => {
   console.log(responseJson);
  
     this.setState({
       loading: false, 
       dataSource: responseJson,
       
     })
     console.log(responseJson);
   }).catch((error) => {
     console.error(error);
   });
}



FlatViewItemSeparator = () => {
  return (
    <View
    style={{
      height: .5,
      width: "100%",
      backgroundColor: "#000",
    }}
  />
  );
}


  render(){
    if (this.state.loading) {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
     <ActivityIndicator /> 
  
  </View>
  );
    }
return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <FlatList
    
     data={this.state.dataSource}

     ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}

     renderItem={({item}) => 
     
     <View style={{flex:1}}>
       <Text>{item.location.name}</Text>
     </View>
     }
         
     keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}

  />
  </View>
)
  }
}
```

Here is some of the json

```js
{
    "location": {
        "name": "New York",
        "region": "New York",
        "country": "United States of America",
        "lat": 40.71,
        "lon": -74.01,
        "tz_id": "America/New_York",
        "localtime_epoch": 1623330602,
        "localtime": "2021-06-10 9:10"
    },
    "current": {
        "last_updated_epoch": 1623326400,
        "last_updated": "2021-06-10 08:00",
        "temp_c": 24.4,
        "temp_f": 75.9,
        "is_day": 1,
        "condition": {
            "text": "Partly cloudy",
            "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/116.png",
            "code": 1003
        },
        "wind_mph": 5.6,
        "wind_kph": 9.0,
        "wind_degree": 70,
        "wind_dir": "ENE",
        "pressure_mb": 1017.0,
        "pressure_in": 30.5,
        "precip_mm": 0.0,
        "precip_in": 0.0,
        "humidity": 54,
        "cloud": 75,
        "feelslike_c": 25.5,
        "feelslike_f": 77.8,
        "vis_km": 16.0,
        "vis_miles": 9.0,
        "uv": 6.0,
        "gust_mph": 12.3,
        "gust_kph": 19.8
    }
   }
```

when I run the app I get the following error

> Error: App(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

Comment: Your return statement is wrapped in `if(this.state.loading)` You have missed a return statement underneath that will wrap the returning code if the component is not loading

Comment: thank you, but it still doesn't display anything

Answer (score -1):

```
import React from "react";
import {
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator
} from "react-native";
export default class App extends React.Component {
constructor (props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    loading: true,
    dataSource: [],
  };
}
componentDidMount() {
  //this.setState({loading:true});
  const fetch = require('node-fetch');
 fetch('https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json', {
   method: 'GET',
   headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
 }).then((response) => response.json())
   .then((responseJson) => {
   console.log(responseJson);
  
     this.setState({
       loading: false, 
       dataSource: responseJson,
       
     })
     console.log(responseJson);
   }).catch((error) => {
     console.error(error);
   });
}



FlatViewItemSeparator = () => {
  return (
    <View
    style={{
      height: .5,
      width: "100%",
      backgroundColor: "#000",
    }}
  />
  );
}


  render(){
  return (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
      {
        this.state.loading ==true?
        <View style={{paddingTop: 20}}>
          <Text>Hello</Text>
         <ActivityIndicator color='#000'/> 
      
      </View>
      :
     
        <View >
           {

             this.state.dataSource.error.code==1002?
             <View>
               {/* <ActivityIndicator color='#000'/>  */}
             <Text>
             { this.state.dataSource.error.message}
            </Text>
            </View>
            :
        <FlatList
        
         data={this.state.dataSource}
    
         ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
    
         renderItem={({item}) => 
         
         <View style={{flex:1}}>
          
            <Text>{item.location.name}</Text>
          
           
         </View>
         }
             
         keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    
      />
        }
      </View>
      }

    </View>

  )
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: check now, I have no access to your API methods otherwise I will show your location name

Comment: let me know if you have still issue

Comment: thanks for your help, sadly still nothing is appearing. I can print the location to the console but can't display it within the app

Comment: Send me screenshots. Thanks

Comment: don't know how to do that, sorry

Comment: I think its the flatlist that isn't rendering

Comment: I took out the flatlist and it worked fine.